# Second key value pair of the multiple Map is not considering as Header in httpHeader spring 4.1.7

Tags: java, spring, http, http-headers, httprequest

I am sending the key and values as below for HttpHeader, only first key and value showing as header. Rest of the key value are appending to another header value

```
 MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();

 headers.add("head1","result1");
 headers.add("head2","result2");
 headers.add("head3","result3");

 HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("this is a body", headers);
```

and then i am getting the request for the webhook like in below link

Please refer to below link for extact formate
    https://webhook.site/#/8362e392-677c-4d29-97db-ba9999bae780/5729b001-de90-4dc5-836f-b0042b526b61/0

```
Headers
content-length  14
connection  close
accept-encoding gzip,deflate
user-agent  Apache-HttpClient/4.5 (Java/1.8.0_161)
content-type    text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
head1   result1
accept  text/plain, application/xml, text/xml, application/json,       application/*+xml, application/*+json, */* head2: result2 head3: result3
host    webhook.site
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure `MultiValueMap<>` is compatible with header spec.

Replace it with `HttpHeaders`, it works for me

```
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

 headers.add("head1","result1");
 headers.add("head2","result2");
 headers.add("head3","result3");
```

Comment: HttpHeaders implements MultiValueMap<String, String>,

Comment: But, internally `HttpHeaders` use Map<String, List<String>> to store header values. Give it a try!

Comment: i tried that too.. its the same. what version Spring HttpHeader you are using?